# How to iterate over the properties of an object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that iterates through the objects properties and outputs only the ones that have a value of `True`.

My starting data is this:

```
UserId                                  : 00546000000m3vCAAQ
UserPermissionsOfflineUser              : True
UserPermissionsMobileUser               : False
UserPermissionsSupportUser              : True
UserPermissionsWebUser                  : False
```

I would like the output to consist of the UserID and only the licenses that are true like the following:

```
UserId                                  : 00546000000m3vCAAQ
UserPermissionsOfflineUser              : True
UserPermissionsSupportUser              : True
```

I think I need two loops, one to iterate over each user and then another loop to iterate over the user's properties and just parse out all the false values.

```
foreach ($_ in $resultset)
{
  $_ |
  Select-Object -Property @{ N = 'UserId'; E = { $_.Id } }

  #This is where I am getting stuck on the second loop.
  #$_.psobject.properties | % { $_.Value }      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Where-Object` to find the properties with a value of `$true`, then use `Select-Object` to select those along with the `UserID` property:

```
$resultSet |ForEach-Object {
  $trueProperties = $_.psobject.Properties |Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $true} |Select -ExpandProperty Name
  $_ |Select -Property @('Id';$trueProperties)
}
```

Be aware that selectively picking out properties based on their value like this may cause you pain later on with `Export-*` or `Format-*` cmdlets

The `|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` part grabs the values of the `Name` property of the properties that made it through our `Where-Object` filter, so at this point `$trueProperties` contain 2 strings: "UserPermissionsOfflineUser" and "UserPermissionsSupportUser".

The expression `@('Id';$trueProperties)` simply concatenates the strings to the "Id" string, so the last `Select-Object` statement is basically the same as saying:

```
$_ |Select Id,UserPermissionsOfflineUser,UserPermissionsSupportUser
```

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed the syntax error.  I use $_.value instead of Value.  I getting the correct output now but the UserId is blank though.

Comment: @PKonstant is `UserId` the actual name of the property? or is it `Id`? It's not clear from the question

Comment: It's 'Id'.  I changed it and it worked!  Thank you.  I understand part of your script up until the '| Select -ExpandProperty Name' and '$_ |Select -Property @('Id';$trueProperties)' .  I am new to powershell and would like to know what statement says to output what?

Comment: @PKonstant Added a bit more explanation

Comment: Just a follow up. Why is $true not a variable; it has a $?.  Thank very much for you help and time.

Comment: It *is* a variable :-) But it's a special constant that always corresponds to the opposite of `$false`. If you have specific questions about the PowerShell language (or it's automatic variables) feel free to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)